# jQuery error in client post response - POST HTTP/1.1" 400

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, flask-restful

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code and I'm not really good with jQuery.
I'm trying to build HTML form will hold cars data. It's based on this form:

[image]

HTML source code [is here](https://github.com/PaacMaan/cars-price-predictor/blob/master/flask_APP/templates/index.html).

Form data is sent on button click on the end back to program.

I upgraded that form with cascading **manufacturer (proizvodjac in code)** and car **models** droplist based on [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/hrvojej/2p6nt5vj/14/). But it's not working.

I keep receiving HTTP 400 which would mean that my POST call from client is malformed.

Here is my jQuery functions:

```
$(function () {

        var carsdata = {"alfaromeo":["mito","156","147","giulietta","159","166","146"],"audi":["a3","a4","a6","a5","80","a1","q3","a8","q5"],"bmw":["320","116","x3","316","318","118","530","x1","520","x5","525","330","120","323","serija 1"],"chevrolet":["spark","lacetti","captiva","aveo","cruze"],"citroen":["c4","c4 grand picasso","c3","c5","c4 picasso","xsara","berlingo","c2","xsara picasso","saxo","ds5","c1"],"fiat":["brava","bravo","panda","grande punto","stilo","punto","punto evo","doblo","500","tipo","uno","coupe"],"ford":["c-max","fiesta","focus","mondeo","fusion","ka","escort"],"honda":["civic","accord","cr-v"],"hyundai":["getz","i10","i20","atos","i30","coupe","elantra","accent","santa fe","ix35","tucson"],"kia":["rio","pro_cee'd","sportage","cee'd","pride","sorento"],"mazda":["3","2","323 f","626","6","cx-5","323","premacy","5"],"mercedes":["a-klasa","c-klasa","e-klasa","b-klasa","124"],"mercedes-benz":["e-klasa","clk-klasa","c-klasa","s-klasa","190","a-klasa","b-klasa","c t-model","ml-klasa","w 124","124"],"nissan":["qashqai","x-trail","note","primera","micra","juke","almera"],"opel":["corsa","astra","zafira","meriva","vectra","insignia","mokka","tigra","combo","astra gtc","kadett"],"peugeot":["308","207","206","306","106","307","208","406","508","407","partner","3008","405"],"renault":["thalia","clio","scenic","grand scenic","kangoo","captur","megane grandtour","megane","laguna","5","megane break","twingo","modus","kadjar","megane classic","espace","megane scenic","megane coupe","megane sedan"],"seat":["toledo","leon","ibiza","altea","cordoba"],"skoda":["fabia","octavia","120","superb","felicia","rapid"],"smart":["fortwo"],"toyota":["corolla","yaris","auris","avensis","rav 4","land cruiser"],"vw":["polo","golf v","golf iv","golf vii","passat","golf vi","jetta","passat variant","caddy","sharan","tiguan","golf variant","golf ii","vento","golfplus","golf iii","bora","touran","touareg","up!"]};

        var proizvodjac = $('<select id="proizvodjac"></select>');
        var model = $('<select id="model"> </select>');
        $.each(carsdata, function(item, key) {
            proizvodjac.append('<option >' + item + '</option>');
        });
        $("#containerProizModel").html(proizvodjac);
        $("#proizvodjac").on("change", function(e) {
            var item;
            var selected = $(this).val();
            if (selected === "alfaromeo") {
                item = carsdata[selected];
                } else {
                item = carsdata[selected];
            }
            $(model).html('');
            $.each(item, function(item, key) {
            model.append('<option >' + key + '</option>');
                });
            });

            $("#containerProizModel").append(model);

        $("button#predict").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            /*Get for variabes*/
            var kilometraza = $("#kilometraza").val(), godina_proizvodnje = $("#godina_proizvodnje").val();
            var snaga_motora = $("#snaga_motora").val(), vrsta_goriva = $("#vrsta_goriva").val();           

            /*create the JSON object*/
            var data = {"kilometraza":kilometraza, "godina_proizvodnje":godina_proizvodnje, "proizvodjac":proizvodjac, "model":model, "snaga_motora":snaga_motora, "vrsta_goriva":vrsta_goriva}
            /*send the ajax request*/
            $.ajax({
                method : "POST",
                url : window.location.href + 'api',
                data : $('form').serialize(),
                success : function(result){
                    var json_result = JSON.parse(result);
                    var price = json_result['price'];
                    swal('Predviđena cijena auta je '+price+' kn', '','success')
                },
                error : function(){
                    console.log("error")
                }
            })
        })
        })
```

Comments and explanations are in the code.

**On server side:**

Server is expecting `user_input` dictionary which is built from variables returned by POST request. Here is how API method looks:

```
@app.route('/api',methods=['POST'])
def get_delay():
    result=request.form
    proizvodjac = result['proizvodjac']
    model = result['model']
    godina_proizvodnje = result['godina_proizvodnje']
    snaga_motora = result['snaga_motora']
    vrsta_goriva = result['vrsta_goriva']
    kilometraza = result['kilometraza']


    user_input = {'proizvodjac':proizvodjac, 
                  'model':model,
                  'godina_proizvodnje':godina_proizvodnje,
                  'snaga_motora':snaga_motora, 
                  'vrsta_goriva':vrsta_goriva, 
                  'kilometraza':kilometraza
             }

    print(user_input)    
    a = input_to_one_hot(result)
    price_pred = gbr.predict([a])[0]
    price_pred = round(price_pred, 2)
    return json.dumps({'price':price_pred});
```

**Error from Google Chrome Developer Console:**

[image]

which is pointing to:
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

I don' know how to pass proizvodjac and model to onClick function. See what happens on breakpoint:
[image]

XHR on Network tab:

[image]

HTML form is being filled with data OK only manufacturer and model are not passed to onClick:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Getting closer to solution. I've added :

```
var proizvodjac = $("#proizvodjac").val()
                var model = $("#model").val()
```

as suggested and now all variables are successfully passed!
But I still get error 400 as final ajax POST call is getting stuck somwhere..

[image]

**EDIT 3:**
changed from

```
data : $('form').serialize()
```

to

```
data = data
```

AJAX method receives everything ok:

[image]

Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Since we can't see what the final HTTP request looks like, and we don't know what the server is at expecting to receive or considers to be valid in this context, it's not really possible at this stage to say what might be wrong. You'll need to tell us more relevant info. Also, does the body of the error response contain any additional details giving more specific info about the nature of the problem?

Comment: @ADyson Information added as requested. I hope that explains it. Server is expecting ´user_input´ dictionary which is built from variables returned by POST request.

Comment: You also ideally should show us what is actually being posted. You can see it from your browser's network log in the Developer Tools.

Comment: @ADyson Ok. I'm on that.

Comment: Compare what the browser is submitting to the back-end (Chrome DevTools - Network Tab - Select the request - In the headers tab: see the last section) with what the back-end is expecting. A bad request is usually returned when the request does not contain the expected data.

Comment: @ADyson I've added Developer Tools output. I've also changed jQuery code since initial one didn't show me manufactuers and models at all.

Comment: @Harvey you need to print the network output, not the console output in the dev tools.

Comment: Go into the Network section of the Developer Tools, and find the call to "/api" in the list (the tools will need to be open already before you submit the form, else it won't log it). Click on that entry. Tabs will appear on the right showing details of the request. look at the contents of the request body (bottom of the request section), and also the contents of the response tab. That is the information we're interested in. We already know what the basic error code is, so your current screenshot doesn't tell us anything new

Comment: @ADyson  I think I already did that. See my edits. Problem is that manufactuere and models variable is not passed to onClick function. Other variables are fine.

Comment: @ADyson I posted it but it's useless. You got more info from break-point I've added.

Comment: " I think I already did that"...you hadn't posted that when I commented :-). But still, it doesn't include exactly what I asked for. My last comment gives a very clear description of what you need to provide. Your network screenshot only provides some headers. The interesting parts will be the request body and the response body, not the headers.

Comment: P.S. The breakpoint thing is interesting now you point it out... do you realise that what you are actually sending to the server is defined by `data : $('form').serialize()` - i.e. it automatically sends the contents of whatever is typed into the form. It doesn't send any of those variables you've defined. If you want to send that object (which _isn't_ JSON, let's be clear), you'd have to write `data : data` instead.

Comment: And two get the values of the two fields you mentioned, `$("#proizvodjac").val()` and `$("#model").val()` should be what you need - just the same pattern you used on the lines above that to get values from form fields.

Comment: But first, as I mentioned, you need to decide whether you can simply submit the contents of the form directly, or whether you need to use your script to create a custom object and submit that (perhaps because the fields in the form don't directly reflect the data structure the server is expecting).

Comment: @ADyson See my edit. We're getting close! All variables from html are passed nicely to variables in onClick function. I'' check all your other comments about what is being sent to server. Thank you so much for everything so far!

Comment: Ok. Did you understand what I wrote in my earlier comment (the one which starts with P.S.)? As I pointed out, you're creating all these variables but you aren't actually sending any of them to the server - you're sending the raw contents of the form instead. That's quite a normal thing to do, but perhaps it isn't adequate here. That's why you need to inspect the body of the request and see what's really being sent. And why you need to inspect the body of the response to see if the server gives you any specific feedback about what fields are missing/incorrect.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I did. See my EDIT #3.

Comment: ok. And the outcome is still the same? We still need to inspect those request and response body values...

Comment: @ADyson Web part is working ok now! Thank you that solved my issue! Can you post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: specifically what was the fix then? Changing to the `data: data` bit?

Comment: Fix was adding var proizvodjac = $("#proizvodjac").val() , model = $("#model").val() and data: data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues here:

1) you aren't getting the values from two of your fields correctly. You need to add

```
var proizvodjac = $("#proizvodjac").val()
var model = $("#model").val()
```

inside the `$("button#predict").click(function(e){` function.

2) You're collecting all these values and putting them into your `data` variable...but then you aren't doing anything with it. Your AJAX request is configured as follows in respect of what data to send:

```
data : $('form').serialize()
```

The [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function automatically scoops up all the raw data from fields within your `<form>` tags. In your scenario, if you want to send a custom set of data (rather than just the as-is contents of the form) as per your `data` object, then you simply need to change this to

```
data: data
```

so it sends the information from that object in the POST request instead.